# Continuous requests to /socket.io/

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, reactjs, hapi.js

I am having trouble pinpointing where my problem is coming from. Currently,
there is a constant request? for `/socket.io/` and I am not sure why.

I checked my developer tools in chrome in the network panel and I don't actually see requests being made. However, the console.logs I put in my code are continuously being hit showing that there is a continuous attempt for `/socket.io/`.

Here is my project:

https://github.com/liondancer/ReviewWeb

I performed a `grep` on my `node_modules` and this was the only result:

```
$grep -rn "socket.io" node_modules/ 
node_modules//hapi/API.md:324:var SocketIO = require('socket.io');
```

I am using `webpack` so `grep` on the file would give me huge, unreadable results.

In my project's `ReviewWeb/server/index.js` I put some console.logs

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function(request, reply) {
    if (typeof request.response.statusCode !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Found server path');
        return reply.continue();
    }

    console.log(request.response.statusCode);
    console.log('rendering server side react', request.path)

    Router.run(routes, request.path, function(Handler, router) {
        var html = React.renderToStaticMarkup(<Handler />);
        // http://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/    
        // Server knows HTML with Cheerio
        var $ = Cheerio.load(HTMLBASE);
        // http://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/#manipulation
        // prepend inserts content as the first child of each of the selected elements.
        $('#app').prepend(html);
        // convert to html
        var output = $.html();
        reply(output);
    });
});
```

This is the result from the console.logs

```
undefined
rendering server side react /socket.io/
Warning: No route matches path "/socket.io/". Make sure you have <Route path="/socket.io/"> somewhere in your routes
undefined
rendering server side react /socket.io/
Warning: No route matches path "/socket.io/". Make sure you have <Route path="/socket.io/"> somewhere in your routes
...
...
...
```

continuously...

Not sure how why this is happening and I am having a hard time finding the source of the problem.

*** UPDATE ***
I was using port 8080 and it was causing a problem. I changed to port 8000 and the problem didn't occur. I have no idea why but perhaps this could be a reason:

http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-mode

But I only have `devtools` set up to be `source-map` in my `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Where in your server code are you listening for an incoming socket.io connection?  I couldn't find that anywhere, thus when the client tries to connect a socket.io connection, it will retry a web request to the `/socket.io/xxx` path over and over trying to connect.

Comment: @jfriend00 after reading around and experimenting. I only have this problem when my port is set to 8080. I changed the port to 8000 and this problem doesn't occur anymore. I have no idea why this is but perhaps a `socket.io` issue.

Comment: Does your client side code make a socket.io connection?  I don't know reactjs so I had trouble following my way through your code to find that part of the code.

Comment: @jfriend00 i think this is the reason why: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html 

However, being new to webpack, I don't think that I am using the dev server? perhaps `devtool` is?